# Suppose X and Y are independent random variables and $Z = X + Y$. Find the density $f_Z(z)$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables defined on the space $\Omega$, with density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, respectively. Suppose $Z = X + Y$. 
>   Find the density $f_Z(z)$ if $$f_X(x)=f_Y(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}2 &, & \text{if $0<x<2$,} \\
> 0 &, & \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}$$

Attempt: I tried to take the integral $$\int_{0}^{z}\frac{1}2,\mathrm dx$$ then I eventually did the integral to get $(z/2)$ and $(1-(z/2)) $. unfortunately I was unable to figure this out

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The probability density function of the sum of independent random variables is [the convolution of their densities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions#Introduction).